# Integration By Substitution： Why are the two results different?

Tags: integration

The sphere: $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2$ is intercepted by the cylindrical surface $x^2+y^2=ax$. Calculate the intercepted volume.

Consider the intercepted volume of the upper hemisphere, and then multiply it by 2:
$$D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq ax\}$$

Now calculate $A$:
$$A=\iint\limits_{D}\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}\text{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_{\color{magenta}{-\pi/2}}^{\pi/2}{\text{d}\theta\int^{a\cos\theta}_{0}}r\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\text{d}r 
\\= \color{magenta}{2}\int_{\color{magenta}{0}}^{\pi/2}\text{d}\theta\int^{a\cos\theta}_{0}r\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\text{d}r\\
=\frac{2}{3}a^3\int^{\pi/2}_{\color{magenta}{0}}(1-\sin^3\theta)\text{d}\theta=\color{red}{\frac{a^3}{3}(\pi-\frac{4}{3})} $$ if I don't change the lower limit of integral, the result would be:
$$
\frac{1}{3}a^3\int^{\pi/2}_{\color{magenta}{-\pi/2}}(1-\sin^3\theta)\text{d}\theta= \color{red}{\frac{a^3}{3}\pi}
$$

Why does the change in limit affect the result?(The two red parts are different)

Comment: The second step in your first approach (changing the lower limit to zero and multiplying by 2) is not allowed since the inner integral after evaluation is dependent on theta and is not an even function.

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal But if you ignore the formula and observe the required volume, the two halves are equal, which means we can simply calculate from 0 to \pi/2 and multiply it by 4.

Comment: The first approach comes from my textbook.

Comment: I got it, the sine cubic has to be in absolute value if I am not mistaken...

Comment: particularly, it should be (sin^2)^3/2 = abs(sin)^3 since sqrt(x^2) = abs(x)

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal Yes! But why?

Comment: please see my another comment above...

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Benjamin_Gal.
In the comment of this question, he pointed out:
$$
(\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}=|\sin^3\theta|\ne\sin^3\theta
$$

And the correction would be:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A=\iint\limits_{D}\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}\text{d}x\mathrm{d}y&=&\int_{\color{black}{-\pi/2}}^{\pi/2}{\text{d}\theta\int^{a\cos\theta}_{0}}r\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\text{d}r 
\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}a^3\int^{\pi/2}_{\color{black}{-\pi/2}}(1-|\sin^3\theta|)\text{d}\theta=\color{black}{\frac{a^3}{3}(\pi-\frac{4}{3})}
\end{eqnarray}
$$